# PHP Stylesheet Links

Tags: php, css

I am currently trying to use a HTML Diff Tool in php, more specifically this one: https://github.com/rashid2538/php-htmldiff
I am downloading the page content of both pages using curl and pass it on to the HTML-Diff.
It does the job perfectly the only problem is that in the result some amount of the linked css stylesheets are external and require a basic HTTP authentication, but the link element does not support url based authentication so simpy regexing in the credentials does not work e.g. `http://user:pwd@some.url.com/sheet.css`.

The only idea I have to remedy that is to search all stylesheet links with regex and replace them with their downloaded content. This seems really stupid and bad to maintenance to me, so is there any better way to do this?

Comment: Or you can just assume that same link means same content and different link means different content?

Answer (score 0):

You could use a proxy.

@see [this answer](https://serverfault.com/questions/239154/whats-the-easiest-way-to-create-an-http-proxy-which-adds-basic-authentication-t) which uses a proxy in apache

```
<Location /path>
    RequestHeader set Authorization "Basic <base64string>"
</Location>

ProxyPass /path http://backend/path
ProxyPassReverse /path http://backend/path
```

An alternative is something @apokryfos suggested. Furthermore, you might use the same diffing on the stylesheets as well. There are also libraries out there, where you can diff not only html. @see [php-diff](https://github.com/chrisboulton/php-diff)

Comment: Unfortunately the tool is intended for multiple pages with varying passwords so doing that hardcoded wont really help.

Comment: sure, you can build your proxy anyway you like. for example your proxy could look like `myproxy.com/stylesheet?originalUrl=...&username=...&password` and then parse the params and build the proxy with it.

Comment: The problem is that the solution should simply work out of the box, without doing any additional server configuration.

Comment: what about my suggestion in the edited answer? @apokryfos might have a point. additionally, why not diff the stylesheets too.